# Change date format in Magento

Tags: php, magento, datepicker, magento-1.9

I am using datepicker in frontend form.

When I save that date in database, time date format is `2015-11-05`.

I am using following code:

```
<div class="field">
    <label class="required" for="birthdate"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Date of birth');?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" title="Birthday" id="birthdate" name="birthdate" value="<?php echo $info->getBirthdate();?>" >
            <img  title="Select Date" id="date" class="v-middle" alt="" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("images/calendar.gif");?> "/>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[

                    Calendar.setup({
                    inputField: "birthdate",
                    ifFormat: "%m/%e/%Y",
                    showsTime: false,
                    button: "date",
                    align: "Bl",
                    singleClick : true
                });
                        //]]>
                </script>
</div>
```

What should I change to have format like `11/05/2015`?

Comment: Which magento version are you using? what error you are getting ? check error log or console log, please. if feasible check once ifFormat : "%e/%m/%y",

Comment: 1.9.0.1 version i m using.there is no error i want to just change format.

Comment: Have you had cleared the magento cache?

Comment: yes i m cleared cache

Comment: Seems you have to change in php class file for date format as
 ->setFormat('%m/%d/%y'), Please check once. Also may be this link help you. http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-date-format/

Comment: try this link http://www.tothenew.com/blog/magento-date-time-picker-in-front-end-form/

Comment: Question : How do I add a backend date picker that returns like 27-Aug-15 instead of 08/27/15?